# How to mount certain SD cards to a specific mountpoint in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, mount, sd-card, automount

Desired behavior:

When SD card1 (`LABEL=NIKON D60`) or SD card2 (`LABEL=NIKON D70`) is put into cardreader, it automatically gets mounted to `/media/digicam`. I run a script, which copies the files to my SSD, renames them with timestamps and rotates them if necessary.

What I tried:

Both cards are formatted in fat32.
I tried to create a `/etc/fstab` with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` containing the following line:

`LABEL=NIKON\ D60 /media/digicam vfat rw,auto`

After rebooting the card still gets mounted in `/Volumes/NIKON D60` automatically.

How to stop the automount to `/Volumes/...` for those cards and get them to mount to my desired folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two conditions must be met:

1. The mount point must already exist.
2. Spaces in the Label Name need to be escaped with an octal space character, e.g.: `\040`

As a test, I did the following:

- Relabeled one of my FAT32 formatted SD Cards to `NIKON D60` then ejected and removed it.
- Created the `/media/digicam` directory using: `sudo mkdir -p /media/digicam`
- Added `LABEL=NIKON\040D60 /media/digicam msdos rw,auto 0 0` to: `/etc/fstab`

I then inserted the SD Card and it mounted as expected, it appeared in Finder as NIKON D60 and its Mount Point showed in Disk Utility as: `/media/digicam`